# Foreign object not being found by Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Edit: from googling I just found out EF7 does not support lazy loading, so how would I accomplish this?

I have the following:

```
[Table("MediaSubmission")]
public class MediaSubmission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual MediaItem Item { get; set; }
}

[Table("MediaItem")]
public class MediaItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string MediaContents { get; set; }
}
```

I create a `MediaSubmission` and a `MediaItem` to add to the database as follows:

```
var item = new MediaItem() { MediaContents = mediaSubmission.URL };
_context.Add(item);

var submission = new MediaSubmission() { Item = item, Title = mediaSubmission.Title };
_context.Add(submission);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return true;
```

Inspecting the database, there's an `ItemId` in the `MediaItem` table which points to the primary key ID in `mediaSubmission`.

However when I iterate over the `MediaSubmissions`, I get a null reference exception for the Item.

I haven't overridden `OnModelCreating`.

Any ideas what's going on?

Edit: just to add this is the `ApplicationbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MediaSubmission> ItemSubmissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MediaItem> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I added `ItemSubmissions` and `Items` to it.

Comment: Lazy Loading is not supported. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data on how to load related data.

Answer (score -1):

how are you retrieving the MediaSubmissions when you say "iterate over the MediaSubmissions"?

You may need to retrieve the Item data for those objects like this:

_context.MediaSubmissions.Include("Item").ToList();

**EDIT:**

To allow lazy loading, try putting this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; inside the constructor of your class that enherits DbContext.

See here for info about lazy loading: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: I'm just looking through it from the dbcontext. I thought it would lazily create the media item when I access it otherwise it would be very slow to create all the foreign key relationships before being requested..